# Error 1120: Access of undefined property e

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to figure out how to fix an error that I am getting with regards to Flash CS6 AS3. I am trying to make a timer to count down from a time that is extracted from a text document and used as a variable. I put addEventListner('enterframe', callback_handler) in beccause that was the correction that an error message said to do now it is saying that something else is wrong with it. I have slightly changed the code as I found a solution to a past problem.

The Code is:

```
addEventListner('enterframe', callback_handler)

 {

 var StartTime:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

 StartTime.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

 StartTime.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

 function onLoaded(e:Event):void {

 }

 StartTime.load(new URLRequest("ResponseTime.txt"));

  var today:Date = new Date();

  var currentTime = today.getTime();

  var targetDate:Date = new Date();

  var timeLeft = StartTime.data - currentTime;

  var sec = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000);

  var min = Math.floor(sec/60);

  sec = String(sec % 60);

  if(sec.length < 2){

   sec = "0" + sec;

  }

  min = String(min % 60);

  if(min.length < 2){

   min = "0" + min;

  }

  if(timeLeft > 0 ){

   var counter:String = min + ":" + sec;

   time_txt.text = counter;

  }else{

         var newTime:String = "00:00";

         time_txt.text = newTime;

         delete (this.onEnterFrame);

  }

  }
```

The errors are:

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListner (Line 2)
1120: Access of a undefined property callback_handler.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of object is "e" and what do you expect getting from `e.data`?

Comment: I am not completely sure, I was told I should put e.data in to get it to work. What should I do instead?

Comment: I have figured it out and changed it. But still need help with two new errors.

Comment: The propert function name is `addEventListener` - you've missed a letter. Coincidentally, it was an "e". :)

Comment: Thanks The error about callback_handler is still there. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your code at wrong place, put your code inside onLoaded function. Like :-

function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
  write your logic here, you can access the e variable inside this block
}